# Encode text string being appended as query to URL

Tags: php, shortcode, urls, encoding

I have a shortcode in use at present that embeds a button on selected product pages. Upon clicking this button, the user is brought to a contact form on another page and the title of the Product from where the button was clicked is appended to the end of the contact form URL as a query string. This product title is then gleaned from the query string and auto-filled into a field labeled "products" on the contact form.

Code as follows:

```
add_shortcode( 'dynamic_contact_button', 'button_product_page' );

function button_product_page() {
global $product;
return "href='/contact-form/?products=Product:%20" .$product->get_title(). "&#contact_form'";
}
```

This creates a URL such as:

```
https://www.example.com/contact-form/?products=Product: Brown Paint - 1L&#contact_form
```

It works quite well... until a product title includes an "unsafe" character which can't be appended to the query string. For example, the apostrophe character **'** to denote measurement in feet in a product title - the query string gets cut where one of these appear meaning only part of the product title is carried over to the form. I'm sure there are many other unsafe characters which would cause similar issues.

Is there a something I can add to the code here to encode the Product title text being appended... so space becomes *%20*, an apostrophe becomes *%27*, etc. I see there is an urlencode option in PHP but my understanding is lacking on how I might implement it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To encode the URL, you could use the PHP `urlencode( $url )` function or use the WordPress `urlencode_deep( $array | $str );` function.

```
add_shortcode( 'dynamic_contact_button',    'button_product_page' );

function button_product_page() {
    global $product;
    return urlencode( "/contact-form/?products=Product:%20" .$product->get_title(). "&#contact_form" );
}
```

## links:

[WordPress - urlencode_deep](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/urlencode_deep)

[urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode)

Comment: Thanks so much @john-zenith. It took a bit of rearranging of how I had the shortcode embedded in the page for this to work but I finally got there. In the end, I removed all static elements of the URL from the PHP code and placed them in the product page instead, leaving just the "get-title" call in PHP. Code below...

Comment: In functions.php: `add_shortcode( 'dynamic_contact_button', 'button_product_page' );

function button_product_page() {
global $product;
return urlencode("" .$product->get_title(). "");
}`

Comment: Front-end code: `<a href="/contact-form/?products=Product:%20[dynamic_contact_button]&#contact_form" ...`

Comment: Example encode: `Fabric (21' x 8')` becomes `Fabric+%2821%27+x+8%27%29` in the browser URL

Comment: Glad I could help @ConM

Answer (score 4):

The [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function is your friend, it's a standard PHP function that encodes strings into URL valid format